tailwindcss not giving privority to css inside media query
my calsses using
flex flex-col m-6  px-12 rounded-lg shadow-2xl border py-4  lg:flex-row lg:py-6 lg:px-8 bg-white
output

herre css in breakpoint is striked out for "flex row"
i found that my code working perfectly on tawilwind play
here preview
but not working on my local maching and aws ec2.
It was previously working fine

Kindly provide the code as text instead of a screenshot.

Seems like you may have included two instances of Tailwind. lg: should always appear after utilities without any variants.
